# C Buffer Overflow - how many bytes to input

Tags: c, security, buffer, overflow

I made a simple C program to try understand buffer overflows. I am trying to overflow the input buffer so that flag gets changed to true and the program outputs "got here". The program is here (assume you have password.txt with **hey** in it):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int flag = 0;

  char pwd[5];
  char input[5];

  FILE *f = fopen("password.txt", "r");

  fscanf(f, "%s", pwd);
  fclose(f);

  strcpy(input, argv[1]);

  if(strcmp(input, pwd)){
    printf("wrong password!\n");
  }
  else{
    flag = 1;
    printf("correct password!\n");
  }
  if(flag){
    printf("you got into the secret place\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

So on the stack we have something like this I guess:

```
[high addresses]
flag   ---> 4 bytes
pwd    ---> 8 bytes
input  ---> 8 bytes
[low addresses]
```

So I think I just need to give the program just 17 bytes to overwrite the flag variable. So i gave it **aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa** but that didn't work. I had to give it **a** 23 times, so 23 bytes. Why is 17 bytes not enough?

Comment: There is no stack in the C language. And there is no use in asking others to explain undefined behaviour.

Comment: I'd suggest disassembling the executable and see how the stack is being used.  Also, you can look at the memory to see where stuff is being placed.  Also, don't forget to account for 'f' as it is stored on the stack as well, which should take 4 (8 if you are on a 64-bit machine) of space

Comment: Do not ask here, do not guess; find out! Use debugger, disassembling, printing. You are trying (for educational purposes of course) to create malware, the path will not be clearly roadmapped and well-lit. Actually some modern compilers will actively try to prevent you....

Comment: Understanding buffer overflows is easy - don't overflow buffers.  If you don't overflow buffers, that particular cause of UB wil cease to be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I used Ubuntu 14.04 with gcc version 4.8.4, and complied your 
code thusly `gcc -m32 -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall temp.c -o temp`.  Different 
compilers, or different options to gcc will, in all probability, give 
different results.

I also modified you code slightly to make it easier to find things,

1. I changed line 6 to  `int flag = 0x41414141;`
2. I changed line 25 to `if(flag==1){`

After compilation I run the executable under GDB, with a break point set 
on main.  And then disassembled main (after setting disassembly-flavor to 
Intel), we get:

```
(gdb) disass
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0804857d <+0>: push   ebp
   0x0804857e <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x08048580 <+3>: and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x08048583 <+6>: sub    esp,0x30
   0x08048586 <+9>: mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
   0x08048589 <+12>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0xc],eax
=> 0x0804858d <+16>:    mov    eax,gs:0x14
   0x08048593 <+22>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x2c],eax
   0x08048597 <+26>:    xor    eax,eax
   0x08048599 <+28>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x18],0x41414141
```

The first four lines are the prolog for `main`  The important thing to 
notice is the line `sub    esp,0x30` where we are setting up the 
stack frame for the function.  As you can see we are subtracting 48 bytes
from esp.  (actually a bit more because we first aligned the stack frame
to a 16-byte boundary).

Now, we can look at where our stack frame is by looking at the values
for ESP and EBP:

```
(gdb) info registers esp
 esp            0xffffd110  0xffffd110

(gdb) info registers ebp
ebp            0xffffd148   0xffffd148
```

and we can find where things are located in the stack frame;

```
(gdb) print &pwd
$3 = (char (*)[5]) 0xffffd132

(gdb) print &flag
$4 = (int *) 0xffffd128

(gdb) print &input
$5 = (char (*)[5]) 0xffffd137

(gdb) print &f
$6 = (FILE **) 0xffffd12c
```

From this we can now deduce our stack layout.  This memory image is 
taken after running past where the program reads the command line 
argument which was the string BBBBB  (recall that the ASCII code for B is 0x42, so it is easy to see a sequence of 0x42 bytes)

```
(gdb) x/56xb $esp
0xffffd110: 0x37    0xd1    0xff    0xff    
0xffffd114: 0xbf    0xd3    0xff    0xff
0xffffd118: 0x32    0xd1    0xff    0xff    
0xffffd11c: 0xe4    0xd1    0xff    0xff
0xffffd120: 0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00    
0xffffd124: 0xe4    0xd1    0xff    0xff
0xffffd128: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41         (flag) 
0xffffd12c: 0x08    0xb0    0x04    0x08         (f)
0xffffd130: 0xc4    0xf3    
0xffffd132: 0x68    0x65    0x79    0x00    0xff (pwd buffer)   
0xffffd137: 0x42    0x42    0x42    0x42    0x42 (input buffer) 
0xffffd13c: 0x00    0xd5    0x61    0x5d
0xffffd140: 0x60    0x86    0x04    0x08    
0xffffd144: 0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
```

Also note, that if I set the command line argument to BBBBBBBB we have this 
for the contents of our stack frame

```
(gdb) x/56xb $esp
0xffffd110: 0x37    0xd1    0xff    0xff    0xbc    0xd3    0xff    0xff
0xffffd118: 0x32    0xd1    0xff    0xff    0xe4    0xd1    0xff    0xff
0xffffd120: 0x02    0x00    0x00    0x00    0xe4    0xd1    0xff    0xff
0xffffd128: 0x41    0x41    0x41    0x41    0x08    0xb0    0x04    0x08
0xffffd130: 0xc4    0xf3    0x68    0x65    0x79    0x00    0xff    0x42
0xffffd138: 0x42    0x42    0x42    0x42    0x42    0x42    0x42    0x00
0xffffd140: 0x60    0x86    0x04    0x08    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
```

Notice that the contents of the flag variable remains unchanged, but the contents of the now overflown input buffer moves toward the top of the stack.  Recall that in x86 the stack grows downward (lower memory addresses).  Also, because the buffer grows upward is why we can use a buffer overflow to over write stored EIP on the stack.

So on my system, I do not believe that it is possible to overwrite the `flag` variable with user input.  You system might lay things out differently on the stack (you would need to do a similar exercise to verify this).

Also, note that the location of the variable on the stack does not correlate with the order that they are declared in the source file.

Comment: Your explanation helped me figure out my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can run into multiple problems when trying this.

- The order of the local variable on the stack isn't necessarily in the same order as the one in the code. The compiler is free to rearrange them as he wish.
- The compiler often aligns data to boundary for faster execution. This means the space between the different local variable can be much bigger than what you think. It's not uncommon to see stack variable aligned on a 8 or 16 bytes boundary even if it's content is much smaller.

You can get the disassembly of your program with `objdump -D` or debug it with `gdb`. This will give you a much better idea of the stack alignment in your program.